# Binding to a model relationship property fails in the each helper

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Binding to a model relationship property fails in the each helper as demonstrated below:

Here are my models:

```
//app/models/category.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr(),
  image: DS.belongsTo('image', { async: true }),
});

//app/models/image.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  thumbfullfilepath: DS.attr('string'),
  category: DS.belongsTo('category', { async: true })
});
```

When I run the category model in the each handlebars helper below to retrieve the 'thumbfullfilepath' for an image tag, no value is bound to the img src:

```
{{#each model as |category|}} 
    <div class="small-element item">
        <div class="cat-name"><a href="#">{{category.name}}</a></div>
        <div class="cat-name edit">{{#link-to 'admin.categories.edit' category}}Edit{{/link-to}}</div>
        <span class="entry-thumb">
            <img src={{category.image.thumbfullfilepath}} alt="">
        </span>   
    </div>
{{/each}}
```

However, I have verified the relationship binding works on display of a single model as when I visit the "admin.categories.edit" route which loads a single category model, the {{category.image.thumbfullfilepath}} path is retrieved and reflected in the template. This has led me to believe that for some reason, model relationship bindings fail in the each handlebars helper within templates.

Would someone shed some light here.

## The solution that has worked for me

I created an image component "image-atom" whose component.js is as below:

```
//pods/components/image-atom.js
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: 'img',
  attributeBindings: ['src', 'alt'],
  alt: '',
  src: Ember.computed(function () {
    this.get('source').then((image) => {
        this.set('src', image.get('thumbfullfilepath'));
    });
    return null;
  })
});
```

Which I use like so here below and it works but it feels hacky:

```
{{#each model as |category|}} 
    <div class="small-element item">
        <div class="cat-name"><a href="#">{{category.name}}</a></div>
        <span class="entry-thumb">
          {{image-atom source=category.image alt=""}}
        </span>   
    </div>
{{/each}}
```

Here below are the environment details:

- ember cli version: "2.2.0-beta.2"
- ember-data: "^2.2.1"
- ember: "2.2.0"
- node: "0.12.7"
- npm: "2.14.10"
- os: "darwin x64 El Capitan"

Let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have a better time simply wrapping an `{{if` helper around you image.

```
<span class="entry-thumb">
  {{#if category.image.thumbfullfilepath}}
    <img src={{category.image.thumbfullfilepath}} alt="">
  {{/if}}
</span>
```

the issue is likely the `image.thumbfullfilepath` is not resolved before the image is trying to render, becuase it is an async promise.

Edit: For the record, working with promises in a computed property in your example, is not recommended. It might be more headache than anything.

Comment: Many thanks for your response.  Will try your solution out and come back and mark this as the answer.  But a quick one, aren't handlebars template bindings supposed to auto-update on relationship properties?  About working with promises in a computed property.  I agree, I had to abandon the computed property solution as it gave intermittent results and opted to side-load the associated image model and it seems to work.  Will get back to you on this one.

Comment: Just verified your solution works.  Many thanks once again!